# Numeric Fields in MS ACCESS Report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a MS Access report that i am trying to pass values from a query, it displays the fields which are non numeric, but in numeric fields it shows only 0 as can be seen in screenshot.  Please suggest what is it that i am doing wrong?

the query is also showing the right data to be displayed, but it doesn't show up in the report!

Please guide

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think you need to use a forum that allows attaching files so you can provide db for review.

Comment: You could try formatting your numeric values in the query. The resulting text value may display in the report. Like this for example - SELECT [Order Details].OrderID, [Order Details].ProductID, [Order Details].UnitPrice, [Order Details].Quantity, [Order Details].Discount, Format([Quantity],"00000") AS str_FMT_quantity
FROM [Order Details];

Comment: It is probably the weird expressions using string handling you use as _ControlSource_ for those fields. Remove these, bind the true values, and use the _Format_ property to set the format for _Null_ or 0 (zero) values.